# Как узнать время выполнение каждой команды в php?

Tags: php, xdebug, производительность

Пишу плагин для автоматической генерации картинок. Все работает, но очень медленно. Хочу определить узкое место, чтобы придумать как его закешировать.

Есть xdebug, но я не знаю как в нем определить скорость исполнение каждой команды при исполнении скрипта.

Подскажите пожалуйста как измерить быстродействие отдельных команд php

PS. Попробовал включить профилирование с вот такими настройками:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_aggregate = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 1
```

Скрипт работает уже минут 20, логи растут, завершаться не собирается. До этого на него уходило где-то 30 секунд.

Нашел чем смотреть эти логи, во всем виноват вот этот код:

```
    function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){
    if(!isset($pct)){
        return false;
    }
    $pct /= 100;
    // Get image width and height
    $w = imagesx( $src_im );
    $h = imagesy( $src_im );
    // Turn alpha blending off
    imagealphablending( $src_im, false );
    // Find the most opaque pixel in the image (the one with the smallest alpha value)
    $minalpha = 127;
    for( $x = 0; $x < $w; $x++ )
        for( $y = 0; $y < $h; $y++ ){
            $alpha = ( imagecolorat( $src_im, $x, $y ) >> 24 ) & 0xFF;
            if( $alpha < $minalpha ){
                $minalpha = $alpha;
            }
        }
    //loop through image pixels and modify alpha for each
    for( $x = 0; $x < $w; $x++ ){
        for( $y = 0; $y < $h; $y++ ){
            //get current alpha value (represents the TANSPARENCY!)
            $colorxy = imagecolorat( $src_im, $x, $y );
            $alpha = ( $colorxy >> 24 ) & 0xFF;
            //calculate new alpha
            if( $minalpha !== 127 ){
                $alpha = 127 + 127 * $pct * ( $alpha - 127 ) / ( 127 - $minalpha );
            } else {
                $alpha += 127 * $pct;
            }
            //get the color index with new alpha
            $alphacolorxy = imagecolorallocatealpha( $src_im, ( $colorxy >> 16 ) & 0xFF, ( $colorxy >> 8 ) & 0xFF, $colorxy & 0xFF, $alpha );
            //set pixel with the new color + opacity
            if( !imagesetpixel( $src_im, $x, $y, $alphacolorxy ) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // The image copy
    imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
}
```

На каждый imagecopy затрачивается более четырех секунд. Не пойму в чем дело.

Решил проблему, исправив метод. Теперь на каждую картинку уходит пару секунд. Вот правильный вариант:

```
    function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct)
{
    // creating a cut resource
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);

    $trans_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($cut, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefill($cut, 0, 0, $trans_color);

    // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    // insert cut resource to destination image
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);

    imagedestroy($cut);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

вы можете использовать xhprof для профилирование приложения в целом.
в убунту прочитать лог можно так:

1. открываем консоль
2. в консоле вводите `tailf -100 /var/log/log-your-site.error.log`

приведите проблематичный код так можно более конкретнее сказать

Comment: Добавил проблемный код в первый пост.

Comment: @AndrewGodin логи можете привести, добавить в пост

Comment: Я уже разобрался. Тормоза прпали.

Comment: @AndrewGodin в чём дело было?

Comment: я в первом посте написал